# How to derive matrices during backpropagation in neural network

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, neural-networks

I'm trying to understand the basic structure of feedforward neural networks by implementing a simple neural network with one hidden layer (3 input nodes, 4 hidden nodes, 1 output node). I've calculated the gradient of the cost-function (squared error) w.r.t. the weights between this hidden layer and the output layer ($\mathbf{w}^{(2)}$) using the chain rule, but when I try to calculate the gradient w.r.t. the weights between the input layer and hidden layer ($\mathbf{W}^{(1)}$) I encounter some dimensional problems. Because $\mathbf{W}^{(1)}$ is a matrix, I end up needing a vector-by-matrix derivate.
$$ \frac{\partial C}{\partial \mathbf{W}^{(1)}} = \frac{\partial C}{\partial \hat y}\cdot{\frac{\partial \hat y}{\partial z^{(2)}}} \cdot{\frac{\partial z^{(2)}}{\partial \mathbf{a}} \cdot{\frac{\partial \mathbf{a}}{\partial \mathbf{z}^{(1)}}} \cdot{\frac{\partial \mathbf{z}^{(1)}}{\partial \mathbf{W}^{(1)}}}}$$

Where $\hat y$ is the outputted value given some input $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{bmatrix}$,
$\mathbf{a} = \begin{bmatrix} a_1 \\ a_2 \\ a_3 \\ a_4\end{bmatrix}$ is the activations of the hidden layer, $z^{(2)} = \sum_{i=1}^4w_i^{(2)}a_i$ and  $\mathbf{z}^{(1)} = \begin{bmatrix} \sum_{j=1}^3w_{1j}^{(2)}x_j \\ \sum_{j=1}^3w_{2j}^{(2)}x_j \\ \sum_{j=1}^3w_{3j}^{(2)}x_j \\ \sum_{j=1}^3w_{4j}^{(2)}x_j\end{bmatrix}$.
All activation functions are sigmoid.

I do not know how to calculate a vector-by-matrix derivative and therefor don't know how to calculate $\frac{\partial \mathbf{z}^{(1)}}{\partial \mathbf{W}^{(1)}}$. I don't even know if i am doing this correctly since all the articles I've read don't go into how to calculate the gradient beyond the first level of weights, and i do not have any previous experience in neural networks. I understand how to derive w.r.t. the weights individually, but don't know how to translate this into matrix-form other than just multiplying the matrices as hadamard products. What is the convention when calculating such gradients for backpropagation? I've read [this](http://cs231n.stanford.edu/slides/2018/cs231n_2018_ds02.pdf) slide from some course on neural networks where they mention vector-by-matrix derivatives, but since I don't know the context of the symbols I'm unable to figure it out.

I would really appreciate some help since this is a school project and can't be omitted.

Comment: See: http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html
You may find it useful for understanding how this can be done.